# All objects in array are equal to last added object c#

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have created a class named "Player" which stores data for each player.
The class does what it should do, but when storing multiple instances of the class in a List/Array, all objects in the array or list are equal to the last stored object.

Player class code:

```
public class Player
{
    private static string player_name;
    public Player(string name)
    {
        player_name = name;
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return player_name;
        }
    }
}
```

code for creating and adding to the list:

```
//simple string array for names;
string[] example_names = new string[] { "Mike", "Adam", "Jake" };

//creating new object and adding to list<Player>
List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
foreach (string name in example_names)
{
     Player player = new Player(name);
     players.Add(player);
}

//loop for returning the output
string output = "";
foreach (Player player in players)
{
    output += player.Name + ", ";
}
Clipboard.SetText(output);
```

output: "Jake, Jake, Jake, "

Comment: `player_name` shouldn't be static

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove `static` from `private static string player_name;` in class `Player`. With that keyword, you are *specifically* telling it to make all instances of `Player` have the same `name`.

Without it, `name` will be an *instance field*, and can be set and retrieved separately for every instance of `Player`.